# angular trigger form submit using anchor link

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular9

I am trying to trigger form submission using an anchor tag from inside the template itself. Its not working as the button control does. Could you suggest how to do it?

```
<!-- main app container -->
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
            <h3>Angular 6 Template-Driven Form Validation</h3>
            <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="model.firstName" #firstName="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && firstName.invalid }" required />
                    <div *ngIf="f.submitted && firstName.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="firstName.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="f.ngSubmit.emit()">Link Submit </a>
                    <button  class="ml-2 btn btn-primary" >Button Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the stackblitz editor  link, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-driven-form-validation-qn6zal?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the form's [`onSubmit` method](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#onsubmit) but it won't cascade a correct `$event`, but you don't seem to need that. Another option is to use `f.ngSubmit.emit()` which does the same thing.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="f.onSubmit()">Link Submit</a>
```

Where `f` refers to your form's template reference variable as in your stackblitz:

```
<form name="form" #f="ngForm">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @robin, onSubmit() works but ngSubmit.emit() is not working.

Comment: Updated the stackblitz code with this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-driven-form-validation-qn6zal?file=app%2Fapp.component.html to show the difference.

Still emit() could be a meaningful solution than onSubmit() but wondering how it work in a reverse way.

Comment: Strange! Your stackblitz with `f.ngSubmit.emit()` worked for me in your original stackblitz (but originally it did not) and both buttons work for me in the stackblitz you've sent in your last comment. That is to say that they both display the same alert message, is it something else that's not working?

Comment: Oh, that's surprising!. I checked the same link in IE Edge and it works there, but chrome doesn't. Which browser did you check?

Comment: I use Chrome aswell :s I didn't check the console for errors the one time that `f.ngSubmit.emit()` didn't work. Did you, maybe there's something being printed?